# Redirecting to an absolute path in NestJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, backend, nestjs

I tried the trick below to redirect the user to a path, however Nest tries to redirect users to `/finance/bank/callback/MYPATH`. I also tried what was said in nest.js documents with @Redirect decorator but it's still the same. Any idea on it?

```
import { Response } from 'express';
@Controller('finance')
export class BankController {
  constructor(private readonly bankService: BankService) {}

  @Get('bank/callback')
  async bankCallbackHandler(
    @Query() queryString: bankCallbackDto,
    @Res() res: Response,
  ): Promise<void> {
    const result = await this.bankService.callbackHandler(queryString);
    if (result.data.transaction_status == 'OK') {
      res.redirect(process.env.SUCCESS);
    } else if (result.data.transaction_status == 'NOk') {
      res.redirect(process.env.FAIL);
    } else if (result.data.transaction_status == 'Duplicate') {
      res.redirect(process.env.DUPLICATE);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your exact problem?

Comment: I kinda figured it out, I was trying to redirect to a route but nest kept redirecting to `current controller path + redirection path`, this happened because in `.env` I mistakenly  typed `ttps` instead of https, where there are no `https` or `http` at the beginning of the redirect route res.redirect does this -> `current view route + redirect route`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the built in [`@Redirect`](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#redirection) decorator. For example:

```js
@Get('bank/callback')
@Redirect()
bankCallbackHandler(@Query() queryString: bankCallbackDto, @Res() res: Response) {
  if (...condition) {
    return { url: 'https://your.redirection.url.com' };
  } else {
    return { url: 'https://different.redirection.url.com' };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ExpressJS way:

```
@Get('google')
public async googleRedirect(@Res() res: Response) {
    // absolute path
    res.redirect('https://www.google.com');

    // relative server path
    // res.redirect('/api');
}
```